# LaTex equation with a "where" that includes special characters

Tags: equations, text

## Goal

I would like to place an equation with a "where" explanatory text for the parameters in which some parameters are special characters.

More visually, I would like to achieve this in LaTex:

[image]

## My attempt

```
\begin{align}
 &g =  m\frac{\lambda}{cos(\theta) 2n}\label{eq:1} \\ 
 &\parbox[t]{10cm}{Where m is an integer (1,2,3… ), $\lambda$ the wavelength index of the medium between the layers} \nonumber \\
\end{align}
```

## Issue

I am getting the following error:

> Unclosed open group

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you say you've encountered. Please post not just a code snippet but a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that gives rise to the issue you would like to fix.

Comment: You can put an equation as single display-math line and follow the explanatory text after it in next paragraph (without empty line between them, i.e there will be no parindent). Why didn't you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't see a need for an `align` environment here; a single `equation` environment would appear to be much more natural. I would strongly recommend, though, that you replace `cos` with `\cos`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
[text before equation]
\begin{equation}
g =  m \frac{\lambda}{\cos(\theta) 2n} \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
where $m$ is an integer ($1,2,3,\dots$), $\lambda$ the wavelength, 
$\theta$ the incident angle, and~$n$ the refractive index of the 
medium between the layers.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: Here's a two-line `align` environment, where the second "line" consists of a `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
[text before equation]
\begin{align}
&g =  m \frac{\lambda}{\cos(\theta) 2n} \label{eq:1} \\
&\parbox[t]{10cm}{where $m$ is an integer ($1,2,3,\dots$), 
$\lambda$ the wavelength, $\theta$ the incident angle, and~$n$
the refractive index of the medium between the layers.} \notag
\end{align}
[text after equation]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. My style guide does not allow this. It needs to be as shown in the picture in the question. Do you see a way to achieve it?

Comment: @james In what does this differ from the picture?

Comment: @james - Please see the addendum I posted.